# Redirecting users to the same Tab in IE in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I am redirecting users to a page based on the value I picked from the dropdown.

```
Response.Redirect("showdetails.aspx?id="+ id);
```

It is working absolutely fine.

Everytime the user selects an iD it is opening a new tab or page instead of opening in one page.

How can I make sure that it opens in same page instead of opening multiple pages?

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: are you adding some javascript to your drop down? Or attaching an event to the dropdown in jquery? If it's just a normal autopostback it should be redirecting within the same page.

Comment: Do you have a 'target' attribute on your form tag, if you look at the source of your page in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited due to rethinking]

What you are describing doesn't seem like normal behaviour.
Does the same thing happen on more than one client PC?
If not it's probably a local config issue.

...or...
is the ASP page called via a server-side control with the following attribute:

```
OnClientClick=”aspnetForm.target =’_blank’
```

If so, that's why.